# Why does tibble add "[, 1]" to new column names created from a matrix?

Tags: r, tibble

In the following example, I would have expected a column named "rn".  Why does tibble create a column named "rn[,1]"?

```
> tibble::tibble(rn = matrix(rep(1, 5), ncol = 1))
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  rn[,1]
   <dbl>
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
5      1
```

This only seems to happen when you're adding a matrix with one column.

```
> df <- tibble::tibble(let = letters[1:5])
> mat <- matrix(1:10, ncol = 2)
> df[, "mat1"] <- mat[, 1]
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  let    mat1
  <chr> <int>
1 a         1
2 b         2
3 c         3
4 d         4
5 e         5
> mat2 <- matrix(1:5, ncol = 1)
> df[, "mat2"] <- mat2
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  let    mat1 mat2[,1]
  <chr> <int>    <int>
1 a         1        1
2 b         2        2
3 c         3        3
4 d         4        4
5 e         5        5
```

This does not happen when you convert to a `data.frame` first.

```
> df[, "mat2"] <- as.data.frame(mat2)
> df
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  let    mat1  mat2
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 a         1     1
2 b         2     2
3 c         3     3
4 d         4     4
5 e         5     5
```

Any ideas?  Is this a tibble bug?

Answer (score 3):

It is based on `drop = TRUE` in `matrix` and `data.frame`

```
df[, "mat1"] <- mat[, 1, drop = FALSE]
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  let   mat1[,1]
#  <chr>    <int>
#1 a            1
#2 b            2
#3 c            3
#4 d            4
#5 e            5
```

This will replicate the same behavior as

```
df[, "mat2"] <- mat2
```

In both the cases, we are assigning a `matrix` with one column directly instead of the `drop`ping of the `dim` attributes when there is a single column or row (because the `drop = TRUE` by default - `?Extract`)

Also, the behavior of `tibble` and `data.frame/matrix` is different with respect to `drop`

```
df[, "mat1"]
```

So, when we do assignment to a `tibble`, the `lhs` and `rhs`

is still a tibble with one column

whereas if it is a `data.frame/matrix`

```
df[, "mat1"]
```

will be a `vector`

```
df <- data.frame(let = letters[1:5])
df[["mat2"]] <- as.data.frame(mat2)
str(df)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
#$ let : Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#$ mat2:'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
# ..$ V1: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

Now, we check the same in `tibble`

```
df <- tibble(let = letters[1:5])
df[["mat2"]] <- as.data.frame(mat2)
str(df)
#tibble [5 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#$ let : chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ mat2:'data.frame':  5 obs. of  1 variable:
#  ..$ V1: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

In both the cases, it is returning a `data.frame` column 'V1', but in the print method for `tibble`, it returns

```
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
#  let   mat2$V1
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 a           1
#2 b           2
#3 c           3
#4 d           4
#5 e           5
```

while in a `data.frame`, it would be

```
df
#  let V1
#1   a  1
#2   b  2
#3   c  3
#4   d  4
#5   e  5
```

If we don't check the `str` in both cases, it would have some consequences while doing some transformations